# Macs CPU temperature increases massively when charger is removed

Tags: mac, laptop, cpu, battery, temperature

So I was trying to kill a Java process the other day. I opened `htop` and looked for Java. This was the first time I really used `htop` so I figured I would set it up in a way I would like. I added the battery, processor temperature and fan RPM meter. To test the battery meter, I removed the charger and the battery showed `Running on battery`. Suddenly the CPU temperature meter went red and showed 129.0 C! I was really surprised because the temperature was at ~60 C before.

## TL;DR

My computers CPU temperature more than doubles when I remove the charger. Is this normal? Why is this happening? Should I try to fix it? If so how would I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You must to reset the System Management Controller ([SMC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Controller)) on your Mac:

Steps:

**Intel-based**

> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Disconnect the MagSafe power adapter from the computer if it's connected.
> 3. Remove the battery.
> 4. Press and hold the power button for five seconds.
> 5. Release the power button.
> 6. Reconnect the battery and MagSafe power adapter.
> 7. Press the power button to turn on the computer.

Complete Documentation [Here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

Answer (score 0):

Addendum to Fransisco Tapia's answer, as many modern Macs don't have a removable battery...

> To reset the SMC on a Mac without a removable battery.
>
> 1. Shut down the computer.
> 2. Plug in the MagSafe or USB-C power adapter to a power source and to your computer.
> 3. On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
> 4. Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
> 5. Press the power button to turn on the computer.
>
> On MagSafe power adapters, the LED might change states or temporarily turn off when you reset the SMC.